# How to tokenize in numpy.ndarray?

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array, nltk, tokenize

I have the following ndarray: X_train: [[<'title'>, <'description'>]]

```
array([['Boots new', 'Boots 46 size new'], ['iPhone 7 plus 128GB Red',
        '\xa0/\n/\n The price is only for Instagram subscribers'], ...],
      dtype=object)
```

So, now I need to tokenize title and description.
I've written the following function:

```
from nltk.tokenize import WordPunctTokenizer


tokenizer = WordPunctTokenizer()
def preprocess(text: str) -> str:
    return ' '.join(tokenizer.tokenize(text.lower()))
```

The question is: how do I process data with ndarrays faster and more efficient?
I do not want to use nested loops. Supposedly there is a way to do it fast with numpy.

I've tried:

```
for row in X_train:
    row = [preprocess(x) for x in row]
```

However, it hasn't changed and I get:

```
array([['Boots new', 'Boots 46 size new'], ['iPhone 7 plus 128GB Red',
            '\xa0/\n/\n The price is only for Instagram subscribers'], ...],
          dtype=object)
```

But I want this:

```
array([['boots new', 'boots 46 size new'], ['iphone 7 plus 128gb red',
                '/ / the price is only for instagram subscribers'], ...],
              dtype=object)
```

Would be grateful for any possible help.

Comment: The fast `numpy` code mainly works with numeric arrays (add, multiply etc).  Your array is object dtype containing strings.  `numpy` does not have its own code for doing simple things like `lower`, muchless complex tasks like tokenize.

Comment: So should I use lambda? Which method would be best there?

Comment: Why `lambda`?  That's just an alternate syntax for writing a function.  It's doesn't speed up anything.

Comment: If you think `for row in arr: row = ...` should change the source array or list, you may need to brush up on some basic Python - what happens when you reassign a variable, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about speed. But I do this with the `map` function.

```
sentences=['Boots new', 'Boots 46 size new'], ['iPhone 7 plus 128GB Red',
        '\xa0/\n/\n The price is only for Instagram subscribers']

def lowr(s):
    return [s[0].lower(), s[1].lower()]
result = list(map(lowr, sentences))

print(result)
```

```
[['boots new', 'boots 46 size new'], ['iphone 7 plus 128gb red', '\xa0/\n/\n the price is only for instagram subscribers']]
```

As @hpaulj mentioned in the comments: the lambda function is just an alternate syntax for a function. So if you want to do the same thing with a lambda function, then it would be:

```
result = list(map(lambda s: [s[0].lower(), s[1].lower()], sentences))
print(result)
```

The output is the same:

```
[['boots new', 'boots 46 size new'], ['iphone 7 plus 128gb red', '\xa0/\n/\n the price is only for instagram subscribers']]
```